# How I can GRANT EXECUTE ON <only 1 procedure OR function in package> TO USER

Tags: oracle, privileges

I need to allow user to execute only one function inside a package.
How I can

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON <only 1 procedure OR function in package> TO USER
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Grant affects the whole package.

Comment: I found something like this

CREATE PROCEDURE <XYZ>
WITH EXECUTE AS <OWNER>
   
Begin
-- Logic
End;

Comment: I don't know what you found, but that isn't Oracle. Check valid CREATE PROCEDURE syntax in the latest Oracle database version (19c) so far here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CREATE-PROCEDURE-statement.html#GUID-5F84DB47-B5BE-4292-848F-756BF365EC54

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create 2 packages:

- main package - contents all logic
- interface package - contents wrapper methods.
  "wrapper methods" - just make calls real methods from main package you want to get access by grant.

And get grants to interface package.